# Convert to camelCase

Tags: code-golf, string

## The Challenge

I was reading [Google's Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case) the other day and stumbled over their algorithm to convert any arbitrary string into camelCase notation. In this challenge you have to implement this algorithm since you don't want to do all this stuff in your head when you are writing your super competitive Java submissions to code-golf challenges.

*Note: I made some small adjustments to the algorithm. You need to use the one specified below.*

## The algorithm

You start with an arbitrary input string and apply the following operations to it:

1. Remove all apostrophes `` `' ``
2. Split the result into words by splitting at

- characters that are not alphanumerical and not a digit `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`
- Uppercase letters which are surrounded by lowercase letters on both sides. `abcDefGhI jk` for example yields `abc Def Ghi jk`

3. Lowercase every word.
4. Uppercase the first character of every but the first word.
5. Join all words back together.

#### Additional notes

- The input will only contain printable ASCII.
- If a digit is the first letter in a word, leave it as it is and don't capitalize something else in this word.
- The input will always have at least one character.

## Rules

- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

## Test cases

```
"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" -> "programmingPuzzlesCodeGolf"
"XML HTTP request" -> "xmlHttpRequest"
"supports IPv6 on iOS?" -> "supportsIpv6OnIos"
"SomeThing w1th, apo'strophe's and' punc]tuation" -> "someThingW1thApostrophesAndPuncTuation"
"nothing special" -> "nothingSpecial"
"5pecial ca5e" -> "5pecialCa5e"
"1337" -> "1337"
"1337-spEAk" -> "1337Speak"
"whatA mess" -> "whataMess"
"abcD" -> "abcd"
"a" -> "a"
"B" -> "b"
```

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: Interesting, I never knew this was called "camelCase". Name is fitting I suppose...

Comment: There are more: `snake_case` & `PascalCase`

Comment: @Martijn `snake_case` because of Python, of course. FORTH also has `FORTHCASE` and APL has `unreadable in any case`

Comment: Test case 4 should have `ApostropheS` in the output.

Comment: @Titus No, it is correct. Apostrophes are removed before the input is splitted.

Comment: What´s the result for `"whatA mess"`?

Comment: @Titus Result for that should be `"whataMess"`. I added a test case for that now.

Comment: oh I just saw that the answer had already been in `"abcD"` Are multiple spaces between words allowed in output?

Comment: @Titus I suppose you mean the input, since the output can't have any spaces in it. And yes, the input might have multiple spaces, but it shouldn't really matter since you split on them anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 56 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
T`'\`
S_`\W|_|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
T`L`l
T`l`L`¶.
¶
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGAnXGAKU19gXFd8X3woPzw9W2Etel0pKD89W0EtWl1bYS16XSkKVGBMYGwKVGBsYExgwrYuCsK2Cg&input=IVNvbWVUaGluZyB3MXRoLCBhcG8nc3Ryb2BwaGUncyBhbkQnIHB1bmNddHVhVElvbg)

#### Explanation

This implements the specification quite literally:

```
T`'\`
```

Remove apostrophes and backticks.

```
S_`\W|_|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

Split the string around non-word characters (in regex this also excludes digits and underscores), or underscores or positions that have a lower case letter on the left and and upper case, lower case on the right. This would create some empty segments when there are two non-letter, non-digit characters in a row, or more important at the beginning of the string. We get rid of those with the `_` option. Here, "splitting" means put each remaining part on its own line.

```
T`L`l
```

Convert everything to lower case.

```
T`l`L`¶.
```

Convert each character that occurs after the linefeed to upper case. This will conveniently skip the first word because there's no linefeed in front of it.

```
¶
```

Get rid of the linefeeds to join everything back together.

Comment: You beat me to it. Nice one!

Comment: This question may be a bit weird, but...should I post my answer if it's shorter than yours and also in Retina? I was working on it before your answer appeared, but then it did and now I don't know if I should post it.

Comment: @daavko Sure, post it (I usually decide based on how different the approach is to the existing answer... if it's the exact same thing with a byte shaved off somewhere I normally just comment on that answer, but if it's a lot shorter of a different approach, then I'd just post a separate answer).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Now that I look at it, it's the same approach, but as a simple expression, rather than a difficult-to-understand (for me, at least) lookaround (or whatever it is). I'll just put it here as a comment: [Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=YCd8YAoKW1xXX10KIApUYExgbApUYGxgTGAgK1x3CiAK&input=U29tZVRoaW5nIHcxdGgsIGFwbydzdHJvcGhlJ3MgYW5kJyBwdW5jXXR1YXRpb24)

Comment: @daavko The lookaround is necessary though. Note that your answer doesn't retain the capitalisation of `Thing` although it should.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh...I didn't notice that. Oh well, I'll successfully answer some other challenge, then.

Answer (score 10):

### Java, <s>198</s> 190 bytes

*+3 bytes because I forgot that `\W+` == `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+` and I need to match `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`*

-11 bytes thanks to [user20093](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20093/user902383) - `?:` instead of `if`/`else`

[Because, Java.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829)

```java
s->{String[]a=s.replaceAll("`|'","").split("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])");s="";for(String w:a){String t=w.toLowerCase();s+=a[0]==w?t:t.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+t.substring(1);}return s;}
```

This is a lambda. Call like so:

```java
UnaryOperator<String> op = s->{String[]a=s.replaceAll("`|'","").split("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])");s="";for(String w:a){String t=w.toLowerCase();s+=a[0]==w?t:t.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+t.substring(1);}return s;};
System.out.println(op.apply("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"));
```

Readable version:

```java
public static String toCamelCase(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s
            .replaceAll("`|'", "") // 1. Remove all apostrophes
            .split("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])"); // 2. Split on [\W_]+ or between [a-z] and [A-Z][a-z]
    s = ""; // Reusing s for building output is cheap
    for (String token : tokens) {
        String lowercaseToken = token.toLowerCase(); // 3. Lowercase every word
        s += tokens[0].equals(token)?lowercaseToken:lowercaseToken.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + lowercaseToken.substring(1); // 4. Uppercase first char of all but first word
        // ^ 5. Join all words back together
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: It's not Swift...

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice first answer!

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy What?

Comment: if you replace conditional statement(if/else) with conditional expression (?:) you could save around 9 bytes

Comment: Don't know how I missed that @user902383 - added for -11 bytes. Unfortunately I had to add 3 as well to match `_` as a token delimiter.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>156</s> <s>154</s> <s>152</s> <s>148</s> <s>145</s> <s>141</s> 140 bytes

*Thanks @Neil (6 bytes), @ETHproductions (3 bytes), and @edc65 (7 bytes)*

```js
a=>a[r='replace'](/`|'/g,a='')[r](/[a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,'$& ')[r](/[^\W_]+/g,b=>a+=(a?b[0].toUpperCase():'')+b.slice(!!a).toLowerCase())&&a
```

Removes apostrophes, then does a replace to split on special characters/before surrounded capitals, then combines with proper casing. Unfortunately, `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` are annoyingly long and hard to avoid here...

Comment: I was working on a different approach which your `b.slice(i>0)` approach blows out of the water, but in the mean time my match regex of `/[A-Z]?([a-z0-9]|[0-9A-Z]{2,})+([A-Z](?![a-z]))?/g` does appear to save 2 bytes over your otherwise ingenious `replace` approach.

Comment: Or I could just save 2 bytes on your `replace` directly: `replace(/[a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,'$& ')`

Comment: @Neal Good point on the replace lookahead! I'll opt for that one, since it takes the least change here. Still, nice matching construction =) I wish JS had lookbehind though...

Comment: Usually `match...map` can be replaced with `replace`

Comment: @edc65 I get a minimum of 160 bytes with that approach: ``a=>a.replace(/`|'/g,'').replace(/[a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,'$& ').replace(/[\W_]*([a-z0-9]+)[\W_]*/gi,(_,b,i)=>(i?b[0].toUpperCase():'')+b.slice(i>0).toLowerCase())``

Comment: Just a first attempt 150: ``a=>a[r='replace'](/`|'/g,'')[r](/[a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,'$& ')[r](/[a-z0-9]+/gi,(b,i)=>a+=(i?b[0].toUpperCase():'')+b.slice(i>0).toLowerCase(),a='')&&a``

Comment: @edc65 Combine that with ETH's alphanumeric regex, and it's down to 148. Mind if I use this?

Comment: I will be glad if you use some of my suggestions

Comment: 145 if you move a='' at the beginning ``a=>a[r='replace'](/`|'/g,a='')[r](/[a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,'$& ')[r](/[^\W_]+/gi,(b,i)=>a+=(i?b[0].toUpperCase():'')+b.slice(i>0).toLowerCase())&&a``

Comment: Ugh, I'd already tried using `split(/[\W_]/)` but I totally overlooked `match`/`replace` with `/[^\W_]/`...

Comment: On the other hand, I would like to offer `b=>a+=(a?b[0].toUpperCase():'')+b.slice(!!a).toLowerCase()` which I believe saves you another 4 bytes.

Comment: Make it tweet-able by removing the `i` from the third regex :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions do you regularly scan through 2/3rd year old submissions for 1 byte savings haha? Thanks =)

Comment: Haha, I just happened to run across this for some reason the other day, looked through the comments and noticed the `i` was still in the regex for some reason. I can't help it if I see an improvement to be made ;)

Answer (score 6):

### vim, <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66

```
:s/[`']//g<cr>:s/[a-z]\zs\ze[A-Z][a-z]\|\W\|_/\r/g<cr>o<esc>guggj<C-v>GgU:%s/\n<cr>
```

vim shorter than Perl?! What is this madness?

```
:s/[`']//g<cr>           remove ` and '
:s/                      match...
 [a-z]\zs\ze[A-Z][a-z]   right before a lowercase-surrounded uppercase letter
 \|\W\|_                 or a non-word char or underscore
 /\r/g<cr>               insert newlines between parts
o<esc>                   add an extra line at the end, necessary later...
gugg                     lowercasify everything
j                        go to line 2 (this is why we added the extra line)
<C-v>G                   visual select the first char of all-but-first line
gU                       uppercase
:%s/\n<cr>               join all lines into one
```

Thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for spotting a useless keystroke!

Comment: I can see why the last `:s` has a `%` but why the inconsistency in the first two?

Comment: @Neil Bah, muscle memory. Thanks!

Comment: Manages to be less readable than Perl, too +1

Comment: I'm totally adding this to my .vimrc

Comment: ggVGJ to join all lines?

Comment: @fruglemonkey 1. `:%j<cr>` is equivalent and shorter. 2. That adds spaces between lines.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica 10.1, 101 bytes

```
""<>(ToCamelCase@{##2}~Prepend~ToLowerCase@#&@@StringCases[StringDelete[#,"`"|"'"],WordCharacter..])&
```

Uses the undocumented `ToCamelCase`, which works similarly to `Capitalize` but sets other characters to lowercase.

Comment: Not in 10.3.0..

Comment: Is `ToCamelCase[n_,m_]:=n<>Capitalize/@m` correct? Seems like it. And why use `Prepend` when `#~ToCamelCase~{##2}` works?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy That gives me `ToCamelCase::argx: ToCamelCase called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

Comment: Well, how does CamelCase work? Just `ToCamelCase[n_]:=""<>Capitalize/@n`?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy, see [this](http://pastebin.com/7YeAAiqG).

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>98</s> 89 bytes

```
s->lcfirst(join(map(ucfirst,split(replace(s,r"['`]",""),r"[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\W|_"))))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach here is the same as in Doorknob's [Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74658/20469): `replace` apostrophes and backticks with the empty string, `split` into an array on a regular expression that matches the necessary cases, `map` the `ucfirst` function over the array to uppercase the first letter of each element, `join` the array back into a string, and `lcfirst` the result to convert the first character to lowercase.

Comment: I've always liked Julia as a more functional, more interesting Python but I hate the `end` syntax. Maybe I'll just use anonymous functions for everything, then I never have to type `end` :D

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 67 + 1 = 68 bytes

```
y/'`//d;s/([a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))|\W|_/$1 /g;$_=lc;s/^ +| +(.)/\u$1/g
```

Requires the `-p` flag, and `-l` for multi line:

```
$ perl -pl camelCase.pl input.txt
programmingPuzzlesCodeGolf
xmlHttpRequest
supportsIpv6OnIos:
someThingW1thApostrophesAndPuncTuation
nothingSpecial
5pecialCa5e
1337
1337Speak
abcd
```

How it works:

```
y/'`//d;                            # Remove ' and `
s/([a-z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))|\W|_/$1 /g; # Replace according to '2. Split...' this will create
                                    #   a space separated string.
$_=lc;                              # lower case string
s/^ +| +(.)/\u$1/g                  # CamelCase the space separated string and remove any
                                    #   potential leading spaces.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 127 Bytes

```
t=''l=t.lower z=io.read()for x in z:gmatch('%w+')do t=t..(t==''and l(x:sub(1,1))or x:sub(1,1):upper())..l(x:sub(2))end return t
```

Accepts a string from stdin and returns camelized results.

Probably still gonna look for a better solution as storing everything in a variable feels inefficient.

But anyhow, pretty simple in general:

```
 z:gmatch('%w+')
```

This is the beauty that saved me a bit of bytes. gmatch will split the string based on the pattern: `%w+` which grabs only alphanumerics.

After that it's simple string operations. string.upper, string.lower and done.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>145</s> <s>122</s> 133 bytes

```
<?=join(split(" ",lcfirst(ucwords(strtolower(preg_replace(["#`|'#","#\W|_#","#([a-z])([A-Z][a-z])#"],[""," ","$1 $2"],$argv[1]))))));
```

Save to file, call from CLI.
Takes input from a single command line argument; escape quotes and whitespace where necessary.

**breakdown**

```
<?=                 // 9. print result
join(split(" ",     // 8. remove spaces
    lcfirst(        // 7. lowercase first character
    ucwords(        // 6. uppercase first character in every word
    strtolower(     // 5. lowercase everything
    preg_replace(
        ["#`|'#",   "#\W|_#",   "#([a-z])([A-Z][a-z])#"],
        ["",        " ",        "$1 $2"],
        // 2. replace apostrophes with empty string (remove them)
                    // 3. replace non-word characters with space
                                // 4. insert space before solitude uppercase
        $argv[1]    // 1. take input from command line
    ))))
));
```

`lcfirst` allowed to reduce this to a single command, saving 23 bytes.
Fixing the apostrophes cost 11 bytes for the additional replace case.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>87</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
y/'`//d;$_=join'',map{ucfirst lc}split/[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\W|_/,$_;lcfirst
```

Byte added for the `-p` flag.

First, we use the `y///` transliteration operator to `d`elete all `` '` `` characters in the input:

```
y/'`//d;
```

Then comes the meat of the code:

```
                         split/[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\W|_/,$_;
```

(split the input string `$_` in the appropriate locations, using the fancy `\K` in the match string to exclude the portion preceding it from the actual match)

```
          map{ucfirst lc}
```

(map over each split portion of the string and make the entire string lowercase, then make the first character of the modified string uppercase)

```
$_=join'',
```

(join on empty string and re-assign to magic underscore `$_`, which gets printed at the end)

Finally, we lowercase the first letter <s>by regex-matching it and using `\l` in the replacement string</s> with a builtin, saving 2 bytes over the previous method:

```
lcfirst
```

Thanks to [@MartinBüttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%c3%bcttner) for 7 bytes (`[^a-zA-Z\d]` -> `\W|_`)!

Comment: How I envy that `\K`... ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>181</s> <s>170</s> 144

```
def f(s:String)={val l=s.replaceAll("'|`","")split("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])")map(_.toLowerCase);l(0)+l.tail.map(_.capitalize).mkString}
```

Tester:

```
val testCases = List(
  "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" -> "programmingPuzzlesCodeGolf",
  "XML HTTP request" -> "xmlHttpRequest"
  // etc
)
println(testCases.map(t=>if(t._2!=f(t._1))s"FAIL:${f(t._1)}"else"PASS").mkString("\n"))
```

Props to [CAD97](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51825/cad97) and apologies to [Nathan Merrill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20198/nathan-merrill) :)

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by replacing `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` with `[\\W_]+`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), 160 Bytes

```
fun a(s: String)=s.replace(Regex("['`]"),"").split(Regex("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])")).map{it.toLowerCase().capitalize()}.joinToString("").decapitalize()
```

My goal was to be Scala, the other "alternative Java", so I'm somewhat happy with my results.  I stole the regex from the [Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74684/20198) answer.

Test it with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testCases = arrayOf(
            "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf",
            "XML HTTP request",
            "supports IPv6 on iOS?",
            "SomeThing w1th, apo'strophe's and' punc]tuation",
            "nothing special",
            "5pecial ca5e",
            "1337",
            "1337-spEAk",
            "abcD",
            "a",
            "B")
    testCases.forEach { println(a(it)) }

}
```

Comment: At this point I think everyone is "borrowing" the optimized regex `\W|_|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` or slightly modifying it eg. `[\W_]+`

Comment: you can save some on map and extension function `fun String.a()=replace(Regex("['\`]"),"").split(Regex("[\\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])")).joinToString(""){it.toLowerCase().capitalize()}.decapitalize()`

Answer (score 0):

## C 272 characters

C program pass string to camelCase in quotes as argument 1.  There are lot's of gotchas in this problem statement...

```
#define S strlen(t)
#define A isalnum(t[i])
j=0;main(i,v)char**v;{char*p=v[1],*t;char o[99]={0};while(t=strtok(p," [{(~!@#$%^*-+=)}]")){i=0;p+=S+1;while((!A)&&i<S)i++;if(i!=S){o[j]=((j++==0)?tolower(t[i++]):toupper(t[i++]));while(i<S){if(A)o[j++]=t[i];i++;}}}puts(o);}
```

Comment: You need to `#include<string.h>` for `strlen`, `strtok`, and `toupper`, and `#include<ctype.h>` for `isalnum`.

Comment: I didn't need it using gcc 3.4.4 in cygwin.  They must be automatically linked in, assuming extern int.

Comment: With `./camel "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"` on cygwin (compiled with gcc 3.4.4), I get `programmingPuzzlesCodeEGolf`. Same output with 5.3.0.

Comment: Crap. me too.  I must've created a bug while golfing it.  I'm looking at it now...

Comment: The problem was I added the other tokenizer strings after golfing and didn't test it well enough.  If you remove the '&' from the strtok call it works on that input.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 123 bytes

```
v=>v[r="replace"](/[`']/g,"")[r](/^.|.$|[A-Z][^a-z]+/g,x=>x.toLowerCase())[r](/[^a-z0-9]+./ig,x=>x.slice(-1).toUpperCase())
```

Readable version

```
v=>
  v.replace(/[`']/g,"")
  .replace(/^.|.$|[A-Z][^a-z]+/g,x=>x.toLowerCase())
  .replace(/[^a-z0-9]+./ig,x=>x.slice(-1).toUpperCase())
```

Remove the apostrophes, 
make the first character lower case, the last character lowercase, and any grouping of multiple uppercase characters,
match any group of 1 or more non-alphanumeric chars + 1 other character, replace with that last character capitalized.

[r="replace"] trick from Mrw247's solution.