# Time to settle this: Java vs C++

Tags: code-golf, string

### Story

In an unnamed company, some people use Java and some use C++. This was always a nuisance, and they kept on arguing which single language they should all be using. To settle the dispute, the management decided that they'll buy a translator program that will be able to rewrite their C++ programs to Java and vice versa. An important part of the translator will be a routine that will rewrite all the identifiers. This is because Java coders in the company write multiword identifiers in a different way than C++ coders in the company do. We will now describe both methods. In Java a multiword identifier is constructed in the following manner: the first word is written starting with a lowercase letter, and the following ones are written starting with an uppercase letter, no separators are used. All other letters are lowercase. Examples of Java identifiers are `javaIdentifier`, `longAndMnemonicIdentifier`, `name` and `kSP`.In C++ people use only lowercase letters in their identifiers. To separate words they use the underscore character '_'. Examples of C++ identifiers are `cpp_identifier`, `long_and_mnemonic_identifier`, `name` (here Java and C++ people agree), and `k_s_p`.

### Task

Write the identifier translation routine/function/etc. Given an identifier, detect whether it is a Java identifier or C++ identifier (as defined below) and translate it to the other dialect. Translation must preserve the order of words and must only change the case of letters and/or add/remove underscores. You may assume all input to be valid, as checking was done for you in the superroutine.

### More formally

A Java identifier only contains characters from [a-zA-Z] and starts with a lowercase letter. Every uppercase character is a word boundary.

A C++ identifier only contains characters from [a-z_] and additionally doesn't start or end with an underscore nor does it contain two adjacent underscores anywhere within. Every underscore is a word boundary.

Translation: switch every word boundary, that is, if it was an underscore, remove it and capitalize the following letter, if it was uppercase, prepend an underscore and lowercase the letter.

### Input

The input consists of one line that contains an identifier. It consists of letters of the English alphabet and underscores. Other standard input styles are also valid.

### Output

If the input identifier is a Java identifier, output/return its C++ version. If it is a C++ identifier, output/return its Java version. You may assume it will be at least one of those (both is possible).

### Examples

```
long_boring_identifier  |  longBoringIdentifier
otherWay                |  other_way
same                    |  same
getHTTP                 |  get_h_t_t_p
invalid_Input           |  <undefined>
```

All the standard rules apply, none of the standard loopholes are allowed.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78239/31625).

Comment: Well, this also requires solving in the other way.

Comment: [Even more closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70180/45941) - given that the only difference is whether the first letter is lowercase or uppercase, I'd consider this a dupe.

Comment: @Mego Dang it, the people over in the Sandbox haven't found any dupes. And it's been there for quite a while as well. Partly due to me putting of making it live. Good catch!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman In fact you mentioned that same one on meta. For sake of completeness you also mentioned the reverse [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74648/convert-to-camelcase), though no-one found a total dupe. Good catch on Mega's part, too bad no-one in the sandbox got it.

Comment: Somehow I had already forgotten, thanks for pointing out the other one! And sorry I didn't catch the dupe beforehand, you did basically everything right.

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 19 bytes

```apl
_(.)
[A-Z]
\u1
_\l&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z9eQ0@TK9pRNyqWK6bUkCs@Jkft//@c/Lz0@KT8okwglZmSmleSmZaZWqQABpwgSSewnCdciiu/JCO1KDyxUgEL4ARLxpcnVnIVJ@amKuAAnCBJrvTUEo@QkADsKoCS8RnxJUBYAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

Contains the unprintable character `\x7F`.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/_.|[A-Z]/g,s=>Buffer(s[1]||''+s).map(x=>x^32))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBC4IwFMDxe59CurhRTqqzQp3q1kEIihrL3myhm2yrFIQ@urmgIOu9wzv8@L8LuzGTalHaQKoTtDxqTRQboqHMWQoopKTZzYPtPszGHSyunINGZjfZN43/8EcGk4KVqIri6jCbYtymShqVA8lVhjga5kpm9Ki06I44gbSCC9BDjL0w9DynixeuPjbofVD2DHrDatd8j/vwUnpndT8zrIDf5J057RcZ2GWSrP9EruiUnqnttmyf)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/_.|[A-Z]/g,s=>s[1]?s[1].toUpperCase():'_'+s.toLowerCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBCoJAEIbvPYV0USmVroFFdSno0MEIElk2HXXDnGV3SYTefXMFg6wZmIH/4/vv9EllKhhXXo0Z6DzUMlxJXwCvaApOQPxXvPGuSVDMDYgXydocX@GZcxA7KsFxlzaxZ7LLjtgMmatTrCVW4FdYOLkzrbAuyA0F6x7LoFYsZyCmrmsFgWUZuu3h4cMmowZUJYgLbY3zPaahp6Sh7ViT9AG/yqAZOjYKUPsoOv2RjNFRUhLVLddv)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>40</s> 34 bytes

```
([A-Z])
_$1
T`Ll`lL`_.
_([A-Z])
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XyPaUTcqVpMrXsWQKyTBJychxychXo8rHiauAlSTk5@XHp@UX5QJpDJTUvNKMtMyU4u4QMJOYFFPhGB@SUZqUXhiJYQRXw5kFSfmpnKlp5Z4hIQEgOj4jPgSICwAAA)

#### Explanation

```
([A-Z])            # Replace all uppercase letters with
_$1                # an underscore followed by that same letter.
T`Ll`lL`_.         # Replace lowercase letters with uppercase letters and vice versa when after an underscore
_([A-Z])           # Replace an underscore followed by an uppercase letter
$1                 # with just that letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

First golf in a while. Comments welcome.

```
lambda s:"".join(["_"*(x!=(l:=x.lower()))+l,x.upper()][p=="_"]*(x!="_")for p,x in zip("."+s,s))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-oextendedglob`, <s>82 69</s> 51 bytes

```sh
<<<${1//(#m)(_?|[A-Z])/${${MATCH[2]:u}:-_$MATCH:l}}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc1BCoMwEIXhvacY0EVCkOJWu@myPUJFQkgnOCBjsNZCy5w9NRTkrb5/8z7PMQWlVQrzAkp1ZMy5KptO67gQrwGqb17T03Cy0poD/aW@D9LW9u92EtmVYczOl0hCP84AJTC@J2KEfOFn3pAJ2WOhiyKAsz5GSw/klQLhktPNbe56lPQD)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanx38bGRqXaUF9fQzlJU0Mj3l6zRiPaUTcqVlNTX6U6N7EkOSPaKBaIrEprYXzjWCvteBU4O6e29r8mV3FqSX5BiUJqRUlqXkpqSnpOfhJXmkJifHJBQXxmSmpeCYjnlViW6Ani/AcA)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanx38bGRqXaUF9fQzlXUyPevibaUTcqVlNfpVql2tcxxNkj2ijWqrTWSjdeBcy1yqmt/a/JVZxakl9QopBaUZKal5Kakp6Tn8SVppAYn1xQEJ@ZkppXAuJ5JZYleoI4/wE)

Even if [the flags count toward byte count](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/86147), adding 14 bytes for `-oextendedglob` still undercuts the 82 byte program!

```sh
<<<${1//(#m)(_?|[A-Z])/${${MATCH[2]:u}:-_$MATCH:l}}
   ${1//              /                           }  # replacement
        (#m)                                         # enable $MATCH parameter
            (_?|[A_Z])                               # "?" matches any character
                         ${MATCH[2]:u}               # substitute 2nd char, uppercased
                       ${             :-_$MATCH:l}   # if empty, substitute "_" and lowercased match
<<<                                                  # print to stdout
```